# How to avoid nesting promises in IF statement

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know we should not nesting promises in functions and all my functions are without any nesting at all however I can't figure out how to avoid nesting promises in if-else statement in one of my function.

```
        const staffRef = db.collection("staff").doc(uid)
        return staffRef.get()
            .then((doc) => {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    return staffRef.delete()
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log("Employee ", uid, " profile has been deleted in staff collection")
                            return null
                        })
                } else {
                    console.log("Employee ", uid, " had no dependencies")
                    return null
                }
            })
```

I don't think this is nesting but I still get warnings while deploying. How should I restructure this code to avoid nesting warning? I know there some similar answers out there but none of them have if else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw an error and catch it, as follows:

```
    const staffRef = db.collection("staff").doc(uid)
    return staffRef.get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                return staffRef.delete();
            } else {
                console.log("Employee ", uid, " had no dependencies")
                throw new Error("Employee " + uid + " had no dependencies");
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Employee ", uid, " profile has been deleted in staff collection");
            return null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        });
```

Comment: Just one follow up questions... We don't really need to throw and catch any error if we don't want to right? Would this code add two same messages in log if doc doesn't exists?

Comment: @ptr.chov With this approach you need to throw an error to avoid the nesting promises. If you don't need the last two `console.log()`s you can suppress the last `then()` and the `catch()`. The Cloud Function platform will "manage" the error itself..

Comment: Yes.. That is how I changed that. Sorry I had to delete my code because I don't know how to format code in comments here :) Basically if I think about it if the doc doesn't exist we will always get log that employee has been deleted but with another  log employee has no dependencies. I have removed last .then and .catch and simply put the log about employee has been deleted before return staff.delete(). Even then in case of error I will get inconsistent logs (has been deleted and then error log)